# Why is TensorFlow producing different output even if I am setting the seed variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In this code I am trying to find the Max and the Max Index of some generated data.

I am trying to verify that I am getting the right Max score.

Issue: If I shift `Line 1` down of `Line 2` I get different output for the generated data, even though I am setting the seed variable. This makes it hard to debug my code. Any suggestions?

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
box_confidence = tf.random_normal([19, 19 , 5, 1], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
boxes = tf.random_normal([19, 19, 5, 4], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
box_class_probs = tf.random_normal([19, 19, 5, 80], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)

box_scores = box_confidence * box_class_probs
box_classes = K.argmax(box_scores,axis=-1)
box_class_scores = K.max(box_scores,axis=-1)

print("box_scores")
print(box_scores.shape)
print("box_classes")
print(box_classes.shape)
print("box_class_scores")
print(box_class_scores.shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    scores_for_box1_anch1 = box_scores[1,1,1,:].eval()
    max_scre_box1_anch1 = box_class_scores[1,1,1].eval()   ###->>Line 1     
    max_scre_class_box1_anch1 = box_classes[1,1,1].eval()  ###->>Line 2

    print("scores_for_box1_anch1 : " + str(scores_for_box1_anch1))
    print("*max_scre_class_box1_anch1: " + str(max_scre_class_box1_anch1))  
    print("*max_scre_box1_anch1 : " + str(max_scre_box1_anch1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `eval` or `sess.run`, the tensors `box_confidence`, `boxes` and `box_class_probs` get new random values. If you want to get results corresponding to the same random values, you need to compute them all in the same call:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    scores_for_box1_anch1, max_scre_box1_anch1, max_scre_class_box1_anch1 = sess.run([
        box_scores[1,1,1,:], box_class_scores[1,1,1], box_classes[1,1,1]])
    print("scores_for_box1_anch1 : " + str(scores_for_box1_anch1))
    print("*max_scre_class_box1_anch1: " + str(max_scre_class_box1_anch1))  
    print("*max_scre_box1_anch1 : " + str(max_scre_box1_anch1))
```